# Grammar rules for Lexer/Parser for populating classes from file

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, lexer

I want to use a lexer and parser at their simplest level possible to solve the following problem

I have a file of which has content of the form

```
TYPE1 ABCR
{

    TYPE2 EFG
    {

        omega 1

        TYPE3 AFGH
        {
            alpha 1
            beta 1 2 
            gamma 1 3 4 
        }   

    }

}


TYPE1 CFGRT
{

    TYPE2 EFGI
    {
        omega 0

        TYPE3 AFGHJ
        {

            beta 6 2 
            gamma 1 8 4 
        }   

    }

}

//.... (more members of TYPE1)
```

I have the following classes into which the above data can be parsed and populated

```
class TYPE1
{


  List<TYPE2> listelems;

}



class TYPE2
{

    omega abc;
    List<TYPE3> listelems;

}

class TYPE3
{

    vec2 beta
    vec3 gamma  

}
```

Now the specification of my file can get changed with say more attributes at every level
and also more hierarchy levels like TYPE4.

Thus I want to keep my parsing generic and extendable.

In this case if I were to use a lexer and parser like Flex/Bison what would be the language
grammar rules to be set for them?

Comment: The parsing currently uses a plain while loop, I would like to move to a lexer parser as my main specification keeps changing, so I do not want to keep editing my code for parsing using the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since there doesn't appear to be any actual Flex/Bison users around right now and since you did say '...a lexer and parser *like* Flex/Bison...', here's how it would roughly look in the (proprietary) parser generator that I use:

```
TYPE1_clause =
  "TYPE1" identifier
  '{'
    TYPE2_clause
  '}'
 .

TYPE2_clause = 
  "TYPE2" identifier
  '{'
    "omega" integer_literal

    TYPE3_clause
  '}'
 .

TYPE3_clause =
  "TYPE3" identifier
  '{'
    [
      "alpha"
      [ integer_literal ]+
    ]?
    [
      "beta"
      [ integer_literal ]+
    ]?
    [
      "gamma"
      [ integer_literal ]+
    ]?
  '}'
 .
```

This makes a few assumptions about what parts are reserved keywords, what parts are variable data, and so on, but you should get the idea.

`identifier` and `integer_literal` are terminals.

Comment: Thanks for this...what is the question mark "?" and "+" for and how do i treat the cases of reading vec3 and vec2 seperately? Also I am assuming you mean that at each of the above rules I will make an action wherein I will instantiate a new object and assign values right?

Comment: ? means that what's in the bracket is optional, + means that what's in the bracket is repeated at least once. And yes, you would have actions that generate objects and assign values.

Comment: In the action code how would I get the individual components of vec3 and vec2 , do we use something like [integer_literal][0], [integer_literal][1], etc for the indivdual components?

Comment: @500-internal-server-error may I ask what commercial product you use instead of flex/bison?

Comment: @Bort: I'm using an internal one that I developed and which I hope to be able to release to the public domain when I can find the time to clean up a few loose ends. It's somewhat similar to coco/r, though if you're looking for a Flex/Bison replacement right now.

Comment: @seahorse: The syntax for that depends on the parser generator.